# Delay of UIButton's highlighted state on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ios7

I created new project in Xcode - Single View app. 
App have only two buttons.

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-40-100, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
[button1 setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"button 1", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.view addSubview:button1];

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-40, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
[button2 setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"button 2", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.view addSubview:button2];
```

When I run this app on iPhone with iOS 7 second button have delay of highlighted state when I press this button. On iPhone with iOS 6 second button works perfect.

Why button on iOS 7 have delay of highlighted?

Comment: Can you show the method where you are adding these to your view. i.e the whole method for this.

Comment: I'm adding this two buttons in viewDidLoad method. This sigle view app is only test app. I want check if button will be have delay in very very simple app - delay like in my 'normal' app.

Comment: try to remove the localisation string and then test

Comment: Unfortunately button have delay with and without NSLocalizedString.

Comment: Both buttons have delayed highlighting in ios 7 or just one? anyway try setting button2.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES; and button2.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

Comment: Only button2 have delay.

Comment: see previous comment, i edited it by mistake

Comment: I was try it and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I got the same problem, but in my case it is a UIToolbar. It works on the simulator but not on a real devices.

Comment: murzynpl, I would suppose that you have some sort of scroll view in buttons hierarchy (collection/table view) and thats why highlighting is delayed. I had the same problem and solved it with disabling `delaysContentTouches` in scroll view. But in that case scrolling becomes interrupted :(

Comment: @brigadir - ditto, I'm having the same issue because my buttons are on a scrollview

Comment: CoDEFRo, in my case I solved this problem by overloading `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:` method. Take a look at my answer to this question.

Comment: @brigadir - thank you for that, going to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was I had a `UIButton` as a subview of a paging `UIScrollView`, so I wanted the user to be able to do a right swipe over the area where the button was without it pressing the button. In iOS6 if you do this over a rounded rect button, it works fine, but in iOS7 it also works but the button won't trigger it's highlight. So to fix this, I implemented my own `UIButton` using the `longPressGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (void) longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressGestureRecognizer
{
    if (longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

        CGPoint touchedPoint = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView: self];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchedPoint))
        {
            [self addHighlights];
        }
        else
        {
            [self removeHighlights];
        }
    }
    else if (longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if (self.highlightView.superview)
        {
            [self removeHighlights];
        }

        CGPoint touchedPoint = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView: self];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchedPoint))
        {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonViewDidTouchUpInside:)])
            {
                [self.delegate buttonViewDidTouchUpInside:self];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you initialize the `longPressGestureRecognizer` and you do:

```
self.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = .05;
```

This will allow you to do a swipe over the button without it triggering it, and will also enable you to press the button and have its highlight trigger. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to overload this method in your scroll view subclass:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    // fix conflicts with scrolling and button highlighting delay:
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        return YES;
    else
        return [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:view];
}
```

Comment: For my case this didn't work out for some reason, but thanks for posting. I also posted a solution I used for the specific case I was having trouble with, don't know if it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the OP just wants visual feedback, but if so, setting the `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` property to YES/true in code or checking the `Shows Touch On Highlight` option in IB will accomplish that.